# How to remove focus of a window which is changing its position property, so that the main window isn't blocked. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window, which just shows an image and a string.
If 5 seconds past I "fade" out the window, by changing its Top property. If this happends it steals completely the focus of my main window and I'm not able to do anything, because the main window is blocked. I've tried this with some native methods, but that hasn't worked for me. Is there a way to remove the focus of this window completely so that it won't steal the main window's focus and doesn't block it, when changing the other window's Top property?

UI xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="Rikkachan.PlayedVideo"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="PlayedVideo" Height="307" Width="542" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" AllowsTransparency="True" 
        WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" ShowActivated="False">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Name="picBox" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="100"/>
        <Label Name="lblPlayedVideo" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Opacity="100" Background="DimGray"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here's the code behind for fading out and stuff:

```
    public partial class PlayedVideo : Window
{
    #region "Variables"
    Rect workingArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
    #endregion

    #region "Initilizing"
    public PlayedVideo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        #region "Setting window at the lower right bottom"
        this.EnableWindowMoving();
        this.Left = workingArea.Right - this.Width;
        this.Top = workingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
        #endregion
        picBox.Source = Screenshot.CreateScreenshotFromWindow("vlc").ToBitmapSource();
        lblPlayedVideo.Content = "Media: " + PlayerProcessInformation.GetCurrentPlayedFile(SupportedPlayer.VLCMediaPlayer);
        StartCloseTimer();

        this.Closed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("I'm dead");
            };
    }
    #endregion

    #region "StartCloseTimer"
    private void StartCloseTimer(double sec = 5)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec);
                timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        for (double i = this.Top; i < workingArea.Bottom; i += 10, Opacity -= 0.099) // look if we get this smoother
                        {
                            this.Top = i;
                            Debug.WriteLine("Top: " + this.Top + "\r\nBottom: " + workingArea.Bottom);
                            Thread.Sleep(200);
                        }
                        timer.Stop();
                        Debug.WriteLine("Timer stopped, now I'm going to die!");
                        this.Close();
                    };
                timer.Start();
            }));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Updated**
UI XAML code:

```
 <Window x:Class="Rikkachan.PlayedVideo"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="PlayedVideo" Height="307" Width="542" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" AllowsTransparency="True" 
        WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" ShowActivated="False"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Name="storyBoardBegin" Completed="storyBoardBegin_Completed">
                    <DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="False" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:3" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" RepeatBehavior="1x" />
                    <DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="False" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Top" From="{Binding TopEnd}" To="{Binding TopBegin}" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="1x"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Name="picBox" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="100"/>
        <Label Name="lblPlayedVideo" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Opacity="100" Background="DimGray"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
    public partial class PlayedVideo : Window
{
    #region "Variables"
    Rect workingArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
    private bool closeStoryBoardCompleted = false;
    private Window m_wnd = null;
    //private Storyboard storyBoardBegin;
    //private Storyboard storyBoardEnd;
    #endregion

    #region "Initilizing"
    public PlayedVideo(Window wnd)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_wnd = wnd;
        #region "Setting window at the lower right bottom"
        this.EnableWindowMoving();
        this.Left = workingArea.Right - this.Width;
        this.Top = workingArea.Bottom - this.Height;

        #endregion
        StartCloseTimer();

        this.Closed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("I'm dead");
            };
    }
    #endregion

    #region "StartCloseTimer"
    private void StartCloseTimer(double sec = 5)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec);
                timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        if (!closeStoryBoardCompleted)
                        {
                            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, (Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec));
                            DoubleAnimation animation2 = new DoubleAnimation(workingArea.Bottom, (Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec));
                            m_wnd.Focus();
                            animation.Completed += (s, _) =>
                                {
                                    Debug.WriteLine("Timer stopped, now I'm going to die!");
                                    this.Close();
                                };
                            this.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, animation);
                            this.BeginAnimation(Window.TopProperty, animation2);
                        }
                    };
                timer.Start();
            }));
        });
    }
    #endregion

    private void storyBoardBegin_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        picBox.Source = Screenshot.CreateScreenshotFromWindow("vlc").ToBitmapSource();
        lblPlayedVideo.Content = "Media: " + PlayerProcessInformation.GetCurrentPlayedFile(SupportedPlayer.VLCMediaPlayer);
    }

    public double TopBegin{get { return workingArea.Bottom - this.Height; }}
    public double TopEnd { get { return workingArea.Bottom; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into WPF Animations. You can do this with the built-in WPF feature set, rather than the code you have. Timers for animation starting and duration are included in the feature set, which is designed to manage UI focus better than you can do with your own Dispatcher calls.

One tutorial that will get you started is found here:

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/wpf/IntroductionToWPFAnimations.aspx

Here is a code-based (rather than XAML-based) introduction to the ideas:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23257/Beginner-s-WPF-Animation-Tutorial

And, the official documentation. The tutorial to make an element fade in and out of view is probably particularly applicable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll take a look to the links.

Comment: I read your links and have done some changes, it works fine, if it is just the Opacity property, if the animation changes the Top property, it holds its focus and steals it from the main window and blocks it, like in my old solution. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: When it comes to animating pop-up toast like that, if you change the Top property you are posting messages to the operating system, so it's not surprising.

At a guess, you could try a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() on your storyboard and set the priority to `Idle`, which stands a chance of working, or, you do what I had to do and animate the Transform properties instead of the Top properties. 

Or, set your animated portion into a larger window or a border of the same size, which is transparent and borderless. Animate within that window and post a close command once the storyboard is complete.